# How to upper-bound the smallest positive root of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Is there any algorithm for (upper-)bounding the smallest positive root of a polynomial of an arbitrary degree if it exists, or detecting that it does not exist otherwise?

*Edit*: I'm looking for a bound that is smaller than the next largest root.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem may be of use to you.

Comment: You might want to refine the question statement.  Would an upper bound on the largest root be satisfactory as also bounding the smallest root?

Comment: What you're looking for is in this book: Theory of equations by J. V. Uspensky, chapter 4.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! @hardmath: good point... I meant a bound that's below the next root.

Comment: This is called isolating or "bracketing" the smallest real root (since by definition zero is a lower bound).  The general topic of efficiently isolating real roots of a polynomial has been studied extensively in the literature, cf. [this 2004 paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042703007271) that builds on previous work with [Descartes Rule of Signs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs).  If only the smallest root is required, some specializations are available.  Would you mind giving an idea of the kind of polynomials you are interested in?

Comment: In particular, are the coefficients given in a form where exact arithmetic is possible, or are we asked to work with "floating point" numerical values?

Comment: @hardmath: Note that I don't want the smallest root, but the smallest *positive* root. And no, there's no exact arithmetic, it's all floating-point -- I'm looking for an algorithm, i.e. something I can reasonably implement on a computer. That said, the polynomials won't be crazy, so I don't expect I'll need to worry about rounding errors.

Comment: I get that you want the smallest *positive* root, hence my remark about zero being a known lower bound.

Comment: Whoops, I read your comment too quickly, sorry. I'll take a look at that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way thanks to the links in the comments above.
One way to bracket the roots is to find a *Sturm chain* as follows.

Here's an example with Mathematica, assuming `f1` is the polynomial. First, find `f2`:

```
f1[x] = x^5 - 3 x - 1
f2[x] = D[f1[x], x]
```

Then repeatedly execute the following and evaluate `f1` at a desired point `x` each time, where `x` is **not** a root of the polynomial:

```
f3[x] = PolynomialRemainder[f1[x], f2[x] , x]
f1[x] = f2[x]
f2[x] = -f3[x]
```

The number of sign changes in the resulting sequence is the number of roots to the right of `x`.
I'm not sure if this includes duplicate roots, but it does seem to include complex roots.

(Taking the difference of two of these counts tells us the number of roots in a given interval.)

Comment: Note that for the given polynomial $f(x) = x^5 - 3x -1$, Descartes' Rule of Signs tells us there is exactly one positive real root (because there is one variation in signs *in its coefficients*).  It would be interesting to see the further details of how the Sturm chain identifies an upper bound on this root.